# How to preserve command prompt's formatting inside a jTextArea (or some other type of console)?

Tags: java, swing, format, command-prompt

I cannot figure out how to preserve command prompt's formatting when I output the stream inside a Java program. Anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Output]

Comment: You need to make sure you're using a fixed width font

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possible solutions available to you depending on how your data is derived...

The most basic would be to ensure you are using a fixed width font...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class OutputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OutputTest();
    }

    public OutputTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            String[] lines = {
                "Idx     Met        MTU        State                Name           ",
                "---  ---------  ----------  ------------  --------------------------",
                "  1         50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Psudo-Interface 1",
                " 11         10        1500  connected     Local Area Connection     ",
                " 11          5        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection 3   ",
            };

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 40);
            ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            for (String text : lines) {
                ta.append(text + "\n");
            }
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        }

    }

}
```

This is great if your piping content from another source (like an external command).

If you have control of the content, you could use `String.format`, but again, unless you're using a fixed width font, it won't make any difference, you will still have formatting issues.

Another solution would be to use a html table in a `JEditorPane`, then the font doesn't matter

Another solution might be to use a `JTable` which is designed to present data in a tabular form.  See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

**Updated**

> It's a bug with the auto generated code in Netbeans 8.0 I'm pretty sure. It just made it tough to track down the issue.

I doubt very highly that it's a bug, as this is been used by hundreds if not thousands of people every day...but without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem it's impossible to know for sure...

> ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13)); BUT if you switch to bold or italics or bold italics then the line is generated and works correctly.

I beg to differ...

[image: Fixed Width Font]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, -1));
            String[] lines = {
                "Idx     Met        MTU        State                Name           ",
                "---  ---------  ----------  ------------  --------------------------",
                "  1         50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Psudo-Interface 1",
                " 11         10        1500  connected     Local Area Connection     ",
                " 11          5        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection 3   ",};

            Font baseFont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13);
            addTextArea(baseFont, lines);
            addTextArea(baseFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC), lines);
            addTextArea(baseFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD), lines);
            addTextArea(baseFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC), lines);
        }

        protected void addTextArea(Font font, String... lines) {

            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            ta.setFont(font);
            for (String text : lines) {
                ta.append(text + "\n");
            }
            ta.setCaretPosition(0);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson The problem is, if the OP is (as I suspect) is piping content from an external process, a `JTable` might not be the best suited solution, as you'd need to parse the text, which would just be a pain in the ... fingers ...

Comment: @AndrewThompson True, just throwing ideas about :P - Added `JTable` as a suggestion

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. I am using a monospaced font already and I've tried other fonts so this isn't a font problem. Yes, I am using BufferedReader to read in each line of the stream. I can't for the life of me think of a solution. What do you recommend with that info?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok so it turns out that it *is* a font issue. The problem is that if I leave it as 'plain' I get the output you see in my pic. However, I tried 'Italics' and it worked! Everything is lined up. Now why would that be the case? And how can I use Plain?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Monospaced at first, that's where the bug is. Then I switched to Courier New.

Comment: Odd cause monospaced is exactly what I used for the example

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's a bug with the auto generated code in Netbeans 8.0 I'm pretty sure. It just made it tough to track down the issue.

Comment: @MadProgrammer When using the Design mode to place a TextArea the autogenerated code doesn't include this line:

Comment: ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));  BUT if you switch to bold or italics or bold italics then the line is generated and works correctly.

Comment: None of my tests have this problem, see update, it MUST be something in you code that you're not showing us

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's very easy to reproduce, and would be easy to fix if the auto-generated code were editable by me. But it's not so I can't change it. I don't know what else it could be since I'm not actually writing any code that handles the font.

Comment: @MadProgrammer And I would post the code that I have if I could but it's secret work stuff so I'll have to make a separate example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Once `initComponents` is called, you should full access to the components to change them as you see fit...do this all the time...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I definitely believe you but I guess I just don't know how to do that because the code section that is generated by Netbeans is certainly not editable by default.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok here is the snippet that is generated by Netbeans (and is not editable). If I change the font to Monospaced Plain the code for it is not generated. Every other font seems to work though. !(http://postimg.org/image/6o3007i8p/)

Comment: So, either change it in the form editor or change the font after the initComponent method is called...