# Formatting JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get the JFrame to look nice however I cannot get it to look good.

I have the following code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReportGUI {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JTextPane report;

    public static Product[] products = {
            new Product("Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2", "CD123455", 28), new Product("Kingsman 2: The Golden Circle", "CD545155", 13), new Product("Cars 3", "CD425245", 24), new Product("The Polar Express", "CD252454", 14), new Product("Harry Potter", "CD452412", 23)
    };

    public ReportGUI() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Report All Products");
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 500);
        report = new JTextPane();
        String txt = String.format("%50s%50s%5s\n", "Product Name", "Serial Number", "Price");
        for (Product product : products) {
            txt += String.format("%50s\t%50s\t$%10.2f\n", product.getName().trim(), product.getSerial().trim(), product.getPrice());
        }
        report.setText(txt);
        mainFrame.add(report);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReportGUI();
    }
}
```

Here is Product.java

```
public class Product() {
    private String name, serial;
    private double price;

    public Product(String name, String serial, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSerial() {
        return serial;
    }

    public void setSerial(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", serial='" + serial + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I want to look like a nice table.

How would I get that to work? I have been trying to get this looking nice for a few hours and I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be great.

Comment: *"I want to look like a nice table"* The use a `JTable` or a `JTextArea` and `String#format`

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How to preserve command prompt's formatting inside a jTextArea (or some other type of console)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922360/how-to-preserve-command-prompts-formatting-inside-a-jtextarea-or-some-other-ty/25922802#25922802)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead.

```
public void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Report All Products");
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 500);

        // create column names
        String[] columnNames = {"Product Name", "Serial Number", "Price"};

        // create data
        Object[][] data = new Object[products.length][];
        for (int x = 0; x < products.length; x++){
            Product product = products[x];
            data[x] = new Object[]{product.getName(), product.getSerial(), product.getPrice()};
        }

        // initialize jtable with data and columnNames
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        // attach table to scrollpane
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        // add scrollpane to frame
        mainFrame.add(scrollPane);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```