# How can i align and improve this multiplication table?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have been assigned to create a program that writes a text file with the multiplication table in it by using a **File Writer class**.

When the program is executed, a JFrame window with table will have to show up.

To do so, i have written three classes namely:

- **MainTp** which runs the program.
- **JFrame** which is the window itself.
- **FileWriteTp** which writes the multiplication table. Here i have used the for cycle to write the table.

Everything works very nicely. Except for one thing. When i run the program, i see the following output wherein which there is something I do not like.

**Output**

[image]

As you can see, the numbers are not well aligned and i would like to get something like this in my output:

[image]

Here you can see that they are very well aligned

After several hours of research, i noticed that it is possible to fix this by using **format**. The problem is i don't know how to use it in this case.

I would appreciate if someone could help me deal with this issue.

Furthermore, i wonder if it's possible to add column lines, row lines and some colors to this table so that it looks better and how it would be done.

Here you have my source code

**FileWriteTp class**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FileWriteTp {

private String pitagora =""; //crea uno "spazio" fra i numeri della tabella

public FileWriteTp() {

    try {
    FileWriter fw=null;

        fw = new FileWriter("tavolapit.txt", false);//con il parametro
        //false il file viene aperto in scrittura e comporta la cancellazione
        //di un eventuale file preesistente



        for(int i=1;i<11; i++) { //creo il primo ciclo per i numeri da 1 a 10


            for(int x= 1; x<11; x++) {//creo secondo ciclo per i numeri da 1 a 10
                //che vanno a moltiplicare i numeri del primo ciclo

                fw.write(i*x +"   "); //istruzione che permette l'esecuzione della 
                //moltiplicazione fra i numeri del primo ciclo(i)e i numeri del
                //secondo ciclo(x)
                pitagora += i*x + "         ";


            }
            fw.write(System.lineSeparator());//istruzioni che permettono 
            //l'incolonnamento in verticale e orizzontale

            pitagora += "\r\n\n"; 

        }

        fw.close(); // chiusura dello stream

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public String getPitagora() { //metodo che permette il valore di "pitagora"e 
    //la visualizzazione dell'intera tabella 
    return String.format(pitagora);
}

}
```

**JFrame class**

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Jframe extends JFrame{

public Jframe() 
{
    super("Tavola Pitagorica"); //assegna il nome alla finestra
    setBounds(200, 150, 650, 550);//imposta le misure per la finestra
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setResizable(false);
    Container c = getContentPane(); //contenitore finestra

    FileWriteTp fw = new FileWriteTp(); //oggetto per fileWriteTp


    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Tavola Pitagorica");
    label1.setFont(new Font ("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,22));
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder (20,0,0,0));
    label1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(fw.getPitagora()); //area di testo
    textArea1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder (50,70,0,0));
    textArea1.setFont(new Font ("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,16));

    c.add(textArea1, BorderLayout.CENTER); //aggiunge l'area di testo 
    c.add(label1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.setBackground(Color.white);

    //all'interno del contenitore impostando il layout al centro
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainTp {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Jframe finestra = new Jframe();
    finestra.setVisible(true);//permette la visibilità della finestra

}
```

}

Thank you so much

Comment: pitagora += i*x + "         "; change to --> pitagora += i*x + "\t";

Comment: ... and `fw.write(i*x +"   ");` to `fw.write(i*x +"\t");`

If shortly - use tabs `\t` instead of manually define distance in spaces

Comment: Thanks dear Faris. It worked and now it looks the way i want it to. 

Thanks dear start67 

Now how could i add row and column lines to this table? is it that hard?

Comment: Use a monospaced font for the text area: `textArea.setFont( new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );`. This would allow you to right justify your number by inserting the appropriate number of spaces before each number. Using "\t" means the numbers will be left justified.

Comment: Use a `JTable`; use `String.format` over `\t` - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922360/how-to-preserve-command-prompts-formatting-inside-a-jtextarea-or-some-other-ty/25922802#25922802)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways you "might" achieve this.  The simplest solution is to use `String.format` and a fixed width font (as suggested by camickr)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            ta.setText(buildTable());
            ta.setEditable(false);
            add(ta);
        }

        protected String buildTable() {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                StringBuilder sbRow = new StringBuilder(128);
                for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
                    int value = i * x;
                    sbRow.append(String.format("%-8d", value));
                }
                sj.add(sbRow.toString());
            }
            return sj.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

Now, of course, if you really don't want to use a fixed width font, you could resort to using a html based table.

[image: Html based table]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
            tp.setContentType("text/html");
            tp.setText(buildTable());
            add(tp);
        }

        protected String buildTable() {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator(), "<html><body><table>", "</table></body></html>");
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                StringBuilder sbRow = new StringBuilder(128);
                sbRow.append("<tr>");
                for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
                    int value = i * x;
                    sbRow.append("<td>").append(value).append("</td>");
                }
                sbRow.append("</tr>");
                sj.add(sbRow.toString());
            }
            return sj.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help xd